# Angular select not allows string with special characters

Tags: angular

when iam trying to set angular form control select  value by using  this.formdata.get('mandal').setValue(this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city),its working when this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city is like "ABCD",but the above code is not working When this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city is like "ABCD(ABCD)" .can use please tell what is issue with it and month is formcontrolname of select dropdown

```
 <div class="form-group"> 
   <mat-label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
      Mandal 
     <span *ngIf='ishownexpertadvisor' class="required-asterisk">*</span>
 </mat-label> 
 <div class="col-sm-10"> 
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mandal" placeholder=" Select mandal" 
         class="select" formControlName="mandal">
         <mat-option *ngFor = "let i of mandalvalues" [value] = "i">
            {{i}}
         </mat-option> 
   </mat-select> 
 </div>
```

Comment: *can use please tell what is issue*. Sure! The issue is that you did not include any code here.

Comment: <div class="form-group">  
                                  <mat-label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Mandal  <span *ngIf='ishownexpertadvisor'  class="required-asterisk">*</span></mat-label>  
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">  
                                          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mandal"    placeholder=" Select mandal"  class="select" formControlName="mandal">
                                                  <mat-option *ngFor = "let i of mandalvalues" [value] = "i">{{i}}</mat-option> </mat-select>

Comment: this.formdata.get('mandal').setValue(this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city) : ''

Comment: Edit your original question instead of write it as comment, pls

Comment: this.formdata.get('mandal').setValue(this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city) : '' when iam trying to append value dynamically  if this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city) is like ABCD value is appending correctly ,if value is like "ABCD(ABCD)", value is not appending

Comment: @abcxyz, remove `[(ngModel)]`. When you use ReactiveForms you should remove it. If you want to give value, give value when create the FormGroup or using setValue

Comment: @Eliseo  i removed [(ngmodel)], still it is not apppending

Comment: Check for errors in the console.

Comment: what is the value of mandalvalues? if is an array of object you need use `[ngValue]="i"`, not only [value]. I don't know if it has special character is necesary use [ngValue]. BTW check what are you sending use a console.log

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing template driven forms with reactive driven forms - you have to choose one or another. This is a common problem people are running into. Since you mentioned that you are setting the value as a reactive form, you need to remove `[(ngModel)]="mandal"`.

I would also use `patchValue` instead of `setValue`, as `setValue` is when you are setting the whole form, whereas here you just intend to set one field.
I would have: `this.formdata.get('mandal').patchValue(this.SingleFieldDetails.contact.city)`